# how to know which pod spec file your cocoapod install is pointing to

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, cocoapods, sharekit

I'm trying to install [sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) via cocoapods. If I search for sharekit on the cocoapod website.. I'm instructed to put this in the podfile:

```
pod 'ShareKit', '~> 2.5'
```

the sharekit pod on the website links to [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/ShareKit/2.5.6/ShareKit.podspec) podspec file, which is tagged as 2.5.6.

so far so good.

But when I run the `pod install` command (I also added `platform :ios, '6.0'` b/c not doing so will throw compatibility errors) I get this error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>   - `SSKeychain (~> 0.2.1)` required by `ShareKit/Core (2.5.6)`- `SSKeychain (~> 1.2.2)` required by `Evernote-SDK-iOS (1.3.1)`

My question is: why is it telling about what **evernote 1.3.1** required? b/c the 2.5.6 podspec has this in it:

```
s.subspec 'Evernote' do |evernote|
   evernote.source_files = 'Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Evernote/**/*.{h,m}'
   evernote.dependency 'Evernote-SDK-iOS', '~> 1.3.0'
   evernote.dependency 'ShareKit/Core'
   evernote.libraries = 'xml2'
   evernote.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2' }
 end
```

so it's clearly linking to **evernote 1.3.0**

the [podspec](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/master/ShareKit.podspec) on sharekit master repo does list **evernote 1.3.1** as a dependency.. but what does that gotta do with my pod install request?

to make things even weirder.. it doesn't matter if i put `pod 'ShareKit', '~> 2.5.6'` or `pod 'ShareKit', '~> 2.5.3'`.. i still get errors talking about sharekit 2.5.6.. why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following explains how pod versions are linked into your project (it goes hand in hand with [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/).

> Besides no version, or a specific one, it is also possible to use logical operators:
>
> '> 0.1' Any version higher than 0.1
>
> '>= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any higher version
>
> '< 0.1' Any version lower than 0.1
>
> '<= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any lower version
>
> In addition to the logic operators CocoaPods has an optimisic operator ~>:
>
> '~> 0.1.2' Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
>
> '~> 0.1' Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
>
> '~> 0' Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.

Source: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

If you want to explicitly link to a specific version, then change your podfile to the following:

```
pod 'ShareKit', '2.5'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve the issue temporarily:

```
# Install 1.3.0 fix pod install error
pod 'Evernote-SDK-iOS', '1.3.0'
pod 'ShareKit', '~> 2.5'
```